# How can I make JavaScript only affect elements within a certain div?

Tags: javascript

I have a select / unselect all checkboxes script, where if I check a specific checkbox, all checkboxes will be selected. But I want it to work within sections, so only the checkboxes within section 1 will be affected by the check all checkbox within that section. Even id's would work. just any way to affect only the checkboxes in the same section tag.

Current script:

```
$("#DE-all-checkboxes").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Comment: show your html code

Comment: [Like so?](https://jsfiddle.net/9ukgw44n/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    Check Uncheck All In Section 1 <input id="DE-all-checkboxes" type="checkbox"/>          
        <div id="section1"> 
            Section 1:
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
        <div id="section2">         
            Section 2:
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#DE-all-checkboxes").change(function () {            
                $("#section1 > input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```